# Data transfer to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm looking for help as I have need to develop data transfer capability to AWS S3 bucket. Data sources are various types like FTP/ SFTP/FTPS/HTTP/ Salesforce and imagines. So far I can see AWS Appflow support Salesforce but still struggling to find ways to transfer other source types. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can try something like s3 fuse and maybe run a script to fetch and populate but I don't know what your volume is like.

Comment: Amazon S3 is an object storage service, which has an API available (see https://aws.amazon.com/tools/). You can send/receive data to/from Amazon S3 via API calls. However, anything more "intelligent" (eg communicating with Salesforce) will need a separate program to do work. There are third-party cloud-based products available that can do this integration, or you can write it yourself.

Comment: thank you for your recommendations. I was thinking to do step functions and lambda to incorporate schedule executions and to perform post computing logic.

Comment: @HimanshuPant : thank you Himanshu. as if now, i know data volume is huge. and on top of that, what is needed is to create zip files , transfer those to s3, unzip and create gzip on S3. looking into S3 fuse.